What happens when PVC solvent cement drop into THHN wire insulation?
Usually when you put wires in a house. You need to connect the empty PVC pipe first then pull the wires. I need to put AWG 1 wire and using 1.5" PVC pipe. There are some corners where I need to insert the wires then put PVC cement to connect the pipes. What if some PVC solvent drops fall into the wires insulation? A THHN wire has nylon outside coating. Can the nylon prevent the cement to melt the inner PVC insulation of the THHN wire?

It will damage the wire.  But regardless,
You are building the conduit incorrectly

There are some corners where I need to insert the wires then put PVC cement to connect the pipes

That's not allowed.  It's a code violation and it means you are thinking wrongheadedly about how to build conduit.  The conduit must always be built empty and the wires pulled in after it is complete.  If you can't do that, then conduit is not correct for your application and do something else.
When following building corners, you typically use "pull elbows" or "LB conduit bodies" to stay conformal to outside corners.  For inside corners, you use "sweeps".
Aboveground, consider EMT
Lastly since you seem to be new at conduit, I'd like to make a pitch for EMT instead of PVC.  Yes, PVC "feels" most familiar and therefore comfortable, but it's a pain in the keister to work with and I hate it. There's no flange that makes everything fit only one way. If you mess up, it's VERY easy to fix since it all un-bolts like an Erector Set (not glued).  So you never face a bad choice of re-purchase $40 of fittings versus leave a bad/wrong installation the way it is.  Obviously there's no trouble with cement, but again, you can't build conduit around wires.
And if that wasn't enough, properly installed, wrench-tight EMT serves AS the ground wire, so one less wire to mess with.
The two things that people balk on are bending EMT and cutting it.  You won't be bending 1-1/2" EMT, but on the small stuff, don't bend it. Buy premade bends.  As far as cutting it, simple hacksaw is it, and you de-burr it with a flick of your wrist with your multi-tool (that's why it's shaped like a wedge).  Never use a tubing bender - that will leave a nasty burr on the inside that will take a long time to file down.

Can the PVC cement dissolve the nylon?

I soaked the thhn wire into the can of pvc solvent cement. The insulation didnt melt. It just gets shiny

You're still building the conduit incorrectly.  That will bite you later.   Maybe you should ask about your actual problem (difficulty routing conduit properly) instead of your proposed solution.  https://xyproblem.info
